# Get previous value of pipeline in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have this code in Javascript:

```
const R = require('ramda')

const f1 = () => 4
const f2 = () => 5
const f3 = value => value + 1

R.pipe(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    console.log    
)()   // output = 6
```

For some reason, I need the value produced by f1() on f3().

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my mind about how I was thinking about the problem.

I thought: if f3() need some value from f1() and f2(), why not explicit that on f3?

I've noticed that using only pipe for this wasn't the right choice.

I searched on Ramda docs and find the converge function.

This resolved my problem (edited from the original question):

```
const R = require('ramda')

const f1 = () => 4
const f2 = () => 5
const f3 = (v1, v2) => v1 + v2

R.pipe(
    R.converge(f3, [f1, f2]),
    console.log
)() // output 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but one possible way could be to use a selector function with `f2` which you can use to control what f2 returns. The function you pass into `f2` either returns `5` or the previous value. Here I have used the K-combinator ([`R.always`](https://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#always)) with the identity function ([`R.identity`](https://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#identity)) to define this function, but you can interpret it as (`K(I)` being `x => y => y`). If you want to get the function to then behave like it previously was and return an entirely new value, you can use `f2(K)` instead.

```js
const f1 = () => 4;
const f2 = sel => prev => sel(5)(prev);
const f3 = value => value + 1;

const K = R.always; // x -> * -> x

R.pipe(
  f1, // => 4
  f2(K(R.identity)), // => 4 (if f2(K) used, then f2(K) => 5)
  f3, // => 4 + 1 = 5
  console.log // IO
)(); // 5
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I understood your response, fix me if I'm wrong. Whether f1() result is been applied to f2() and f2() result is been applied on f3(), that's make sense that f2 control what is inputed in f3 right?

Comment: yes, the output of f1 goes to f2, this same values is returned from f2 and given to f3.